# How can I check if string is from this format?

Tags: bash

How can I check if a string in bash is from this format: `exerciseNumber{N}Published` while **{N}** is some natural number.

for example:

```
for file in `ls`; do
  if (( `isInRequiredFormat ${file}` )); then
    echo Yes.
  fi
done
```

And I ask for how can I write the function "isInRequiredFormat" according to the format the I writed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use (extended) pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *; do
  if [[ $file = exerciseNumber@(0|[1-9]*([0-9]))Published ]]; then
    echo yes
  fi
done
```

`@(x|y)` matches either `x` or `y`. `*(x)` matches 0 or more occurrences of `x`. So `@(0|[1-9]*([0-9]))` matches either 0, or it matches a non-zero digit optionally followed by any number of digits.

Comment: Just some math background, natural numbers don't start from 0 ;)

Comment: Depends on who you ask. There are perfectly good reasons to define the natural numbers as the non-negative integers.

Comment: @chepner Can you explain why you don't write `==` insetead `=` , and what is the operator `+([0-9])` ?

Comment: `=` was faster to type? :) Seriously, I didn't even notice I had. `=` and `==` are both equality operators, with `=` being the original, standard operator and `==` the more "modern" one that `[[` supports as well. `+(...)` is the extended pattern operator that matches one or more of whatever pattern occurs in the parentheses.

Comment: @chepner Can you give me please a reference about `+(...)` for reading about this operator? (I don't find it after searching in google)

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching.

Comment: @chepner By the way, after a little checking, can you fix your code such then `032` or `012` (or any other number that starting with 0 apart of 0) will not be valid numbers for {N} ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression.

```
for file in `ls`; do
  if [[ $file =~ exerciseNumber[:digit:]*Published ]]; then
    echo Yes.
  fi
done
```